# Optimization of a farmer

Tags: calculus

I have no idea why I am getting the wrong answer again.

A farmer wants to fence an area of 1.5 million square feet in a rectangular field and then divide it in half with a fence parallel to one of the sides. How can he do this so as to minimize the cost of the fence?

I know that my two functions are

$l2w = 1.5million$ where l is length and w is width which I will have two of since it is cut in half by a parallel fence.

$2l + 3w = p$ this is because there are 2 length sections and 3 width since a parallel fence adds one length.

I subsitute in

$\frac {1500000}{w} + 3w = a$

the derivative

$\frac{-1500000}{w^2} + 3 = a$

find the zero gives me nonsense and a wrong answer.

Comment: If each of the fenced-off rectangular sub-areas have a width of $w$ and a length of $l$ (with the fence in the middle having a length of $w$), then wouldn't the perimeter be $4l+3w$?

Comment: I am still getting the wrong answer.

Comment: Well, show more work in your question.

Comment: Hmm, optimization of a farmer? What property of him are you trying to optimize?

Comment: I am trying to optimize the farmer's income. I got the answer, I am incredibly bad at these.

Comment: The error here is the same as in your most recent question: you are using $l$ sometimes to mean "length of the entire rectangle" and sometimes to mean "length of the subrectangles". Writing down *explicitly* what your variables mean before you start will be helpful for any word problem you face.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only made one computational error and a notational error.

Here is your solution (at least the first part that follows) re-written:

You are minimizing the cost of the fence, so you want to minimize the perimeter of the enclosure. The perimeter $P$
is
$$\tag{1}
P=2l+3w.
$$ 
where $l$ is the length and $w$ is the width of the enclosure. It is assumed the division of the original fence is made across a width (hence the  $3w$).

We want to write $P$ in terms of one variable. For this we use the given information that the area is $1.5\cdot10^6\,\rm ft^2$. So $$lw= 1.5\cdot10^6\,\rm ft^2,$$ or, 
$$\tag{2}
l={1.5\cdot10^6\over w}
$$
Substituting $(2)$ into $(1)$ gives
$$
P=2\bigl({1.5\cdot10^6\over w}\bigr) +3w
$$
or
$$
P(w)= {3\cdot10^6\over w}  +3w
$$
(this is where you made your mistake).

We also need to find the appropriate range of values for $w$. Here, $w$ could be possibly any positive, finite length.

So, you want to find the minimum value of $P$ over the interval $(0,\infty)$.

Towards this end, evaluate
$$
P'(w)= - {3\cdot10^6\over w^2}  +3.
$$
Set $P'(w)=0$ and find the solutions in the interval  $(0,\infty)$:
$$
- {3\cdot10^6\over w^2}  +3 = 0 \quad\iff\quad {3\cdot10^6 }  =3w^2\quad\iff\quad w=10^3.
$$

So $w=1000\,\rm ft$ gives the only critical point of $P$ in the interval $(0,\infty)$. 
We need to examine what goes on near the endpoints of our interval before declaring that $1000\,\rm ft$ gives the answer. 
As you can easily convince yourself $\lim\limits_{w\rightarrow 0^+} P(w)$ and $\lim\limits_{w\rightarrow \infty} P(w)$ are both infinite. So the cost of the enclosure is minimized when $w=1000\,\rm ft$.

And to explicitly answer the question (don't forget to do this): "he can do this by taking the width to be $1000\,\rm ft$, the length to be ${1.5\cdot 10^6\over1000}=1500\,\rm ft$ and spliting the enclosure by constructing another width".

Answer (score 1):

The field is 1.5M ft^2 before the division, so you should have $lw=1.5M$.  You are right that the cost is $2l+3w=p=3w+3M/w$.  You used $p$ earlier and $a$ later for the total cost, and $\frac {da}{dw}=0$, not $a$.  Now take the derivative with respect to $w$ and you should be home.